# Choose dynamically a property of the component

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following simple code:

```
export class TestComponent {
    mobileMessage: string;
    private mobileValidationMessages:ISchemeObject = {
        required: "Mobile is required",
        pattern:  "Mobile format is not correct"
    }

    setMessage(controlName: string): void {
        const x = <any>(controlName + "Message");
        this[x] = "Something";
    } 
}
```

With the above I want to call **setMessage()** with any argument I like, e.g. 
`setMessage("mobile")` and be able to change `mobileMessage`. However, Typescript is complaining and does not allow me to do that. How may I achieve that?

Comment: What error do you get? This looks like it should work.

Comment: Yeah this works for me

Comment: Element implicitly has an any type because type TestComponent has no index signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could restrict the string to keys of the class itself to make it more type safe

```
export class TestComponent {

  mobileMessage: string

  setMessage(messageProp: keyof this): void {
      this[messageProp] = 'Something'
  }

  example(): void {
    this.setMessage('mobileMessage')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Type something like:

```
export class TestComponent {
 field: {[key: string]: string};

 setValue(fieldName: string, value: string) {
   this.field[fieldName] = value;
}
```